# How do I make a database column a function of another column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a database column which would be the percent of the value in another column

```
<?php
$sql = "ALTER TABLE inventorylist
        ADD COLUMN percent DOUBLE 
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (turnover/SUM(turnover)*100);"; 
?>
```

Comment: If `sum(turnover)` means you would like to sum the turnover column up, then it is not going to work, since expressions in generated columns cannot work with other rows or tables. You may want to create a view instead.

Comment: In case it's not clear to the OP, using a view is possible but you still won't be able to just do `turnover/SUM(turnover)` because the `SUM` is an aggregate function that implies row grouping. You could use a subquery in the view like `turnover/(select sum(turnover) from inventorylist)` but that's pretty inefficient. Also note that if you end up trying to use aggregation/grouping in a view it can impact the [optimization algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html). If performance is a concern aggregate your stats periodically in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented generated columns can only refer to the columns of the same row. But you could try a view including the calculation. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE VIEW inventorylist_with_percent
AS
SELECT il1.*,
       il1.turnover / (SELECT sum(il2.turnover)
                              FROM inventorylist il2) * 100 percent
       FROM inventorylist il1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will safe to say let your code logic handle that task instead of pushing it to the database. Write a code that does the computation while inserting or while querying from the database.